# WCF Proxy bypasslist in the binding

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I understand that to add a proxy in a WCF 4.0  application you must add it to the Binding in the config file.  But what if you need to add a proxy exception like the "bypass list example here?  Will a general section like this work or is there a way to add a exception to a binding?

```
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        usesystemdefaults="true"
        proxyaddress="http://192.168.1.10:3128"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
      <bypasslist
        <add address="[a-z]+\.contoso\.com" />
      </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: `192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` ? `[a-z]+\.labcrm2015\.com$` ? is valid `https://www.nuget.org/api/*` ?